# how to make dropdown width (background) follow parent li without using media queries Css only

Tags: html, css

There is a question very similar to this one which already been solved, yet that solution is not helping me.

The issue I'm facing is the dropdown is not following its parent width ( `position: absolute` is in play here) and I think `position: absolute` is the only way to stop the whole nav bar to expand when the dropdown is accessed.

so is there any way I can make dropdown follow its parent width other than using media queries and defining a width for every device?

And forgive me if I'm not able to explain myself clearly. **Beginner here**.

**Thanks**

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    background: #9999ff;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: space-around;
    line-height: 2;

}

li {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center !important;
    flex-grow: 1;  

}

.drop{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    background-color: #9999ff;
    line-height: 3;
    /*width: 17em;*/
}
.drop li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    text-align: center;
}

li:hover {
    background: black;
    color: plum;
}

li:hover .drop {
    visibility: visible;
    
}

.drop li:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>JS
        <ul class="drop">
            <li>Node</li>
            <li>React</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    background: #9999ff;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: space-around;
    line-height: 2;

}

li {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center !important;
    flex-grow: 1;  

}

.drop{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    background-color: #9999ff;
    line-height: 3;
    /*width: 17em;*/
   
    
    
}
.drop li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    text-align: center;
}

li:hover {
    background: black;
    color: plum;
}

li:hover .drop {
    visibility: visible;
    
}

.drop li:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>JS
            <ul class="drop">
                <li>Node</li>
                <li>React</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: yes, position:absolute pulls your element from regular flow. And visibility:hidden acts like your element is there, but just hidden. Display:none is what you need - it both hides the element and removes the element border box. if that makes sense. Is there a way that you can set width, maybe as a percentage?

Comment: @Lalalena I  tried using ``display: none`` but the issue was the whole navbar is expanding on hover, not just the dropdown list.  And yes if I don't have to change the width for every device manually I have no issue using the percentage.

Comment: @Lalalena if I may ask how can this problem be solved with javascript, Can you help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for fixed number of items, all with the same width:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    background: #9999ff;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: space-around;
    line-height: 2;

}

li {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center !important;
    flex-grow: 1;  
    width: calc(100vw / 4 - 15px);
}

.drop{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    background-color: #9999ff;
    line-height: 3;
    /*width: 17em;*/
   
    
    
}
.drop li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    text-align: center;
}

li:hover {
    background: black;
    color: plum;
}

li:hover .drop {
    visibility: visible;
    
}

.drop li:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>JS
            <ul class="drop">
                <li>Node</li>
                <li>React</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ul>
```

Relevant snippet:

```css
       li {
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align: center !important;
          flex-grow: 1;  
          width: calc(100vw / 4 - 15px); // full viewport width divided by number of elements, minus paddings
        }
```

Explanation: Viewport width takes into account the entire viewport width. Divide this by the number of items in our header, and we get our item width.
Now this does not take into account paddings, margins and similar, so you have to supply that yourself - but `calc()` is pretty flexible for this, as long as you know about the actual value of these factors.

Comment: How did you find the padding?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround to fix your problem. It might not be the prettiest but it works!

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #9999ff 44px, transparent 0px);
    list-style: none;
    padding: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: space-around;
    line-height: 2;

}

li {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center !important;
    flex-grow: 1;  

}

.drop{
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    background-color: #9999ff;
    line-height: 3;
    /*width: 17em;*/
   
    
    
}
.drop li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    text-align: center;
}

li:hover {
    background: black;
    color: plum;
}

li:hover .drop {
    display: block;
    background: #9999ff;
}

.drop li:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>JS
            <ul class="drop">
                <li>Node</li>
                <li>React</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ul>
```

Problem:

We need our `.drop` element to NOT have position:absolute (because we need to access its parent's width), and we also cannot specify a maximum height for the header itself, as the overflowing dropdown would be hidden from view.

Solution:
We set the background of the header to a `linear-gradient` which has a specified height of 44px for purple color, and 0px for transparent.
This means that even if the header changes height, the background gradient color will always have the same height.
As a result, the header itself WILL change size, but it is not visually detectable.

Is it a pretty solution? No.
Is it good practice? Probably not.
Does it work? Well, it does!

I suggest using javascript for similar problems in the future though :)

Comment: Well, I'm not yet marking my question solved yet.  But this solution definitely solved the problem and you deserve an upvote. Thanks for helping